# HJCached images cause lags in table view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, lag

I am writing an application for a sushi bar. The menu hierarchy consisting of a *table view (custom cell)* **==>** *table view (custom cell)* **==>** *view*

In the first Table View there is pictures of food categories (picture taken from the first dish in this category), in the second - pictures of dishes, in a description view - the same dish image, but in larger size.

Pictures are downloaded asynchronously from the links (which are parsed from json menu) and cached by the library HJCache. Everything works, everything is loaded, but .. When scrolling tableview there are some lags - I mean scrolling is not smooth. I thought that was memory leak, but found nothing.

The original size of pictures - something about 450/300, in a custom table cell, it must fit in 120/80. Can the program be slow and laggy because of too large size pictures?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly urge you to see if they could get those images resized on the server. There is really no reason at all to download 300-450 px per dimension images if they are going to be sized down to fit in a table cell. If I had to make a guess as to the performance hit (and its only a guess), it would be that the scrolling performance hit is caused by finishing loading the image and trying to add it to the `UIImageView` by resizing it (probably have Aspect for Fill or something similar set?).

The short answer to your question: yes, its very likely the large images are the performance hit. Even if they are downloaded async, there is no reason to transfer more data than you need to.